# Fanybox Next Prev not working for type HTML properly

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox-2

I have been trying to use same fancybox function for multiple file type like image, video and PDF. so far it's working but the problem is when i open image and click on next button it shows me same image and not going forward to video and then next to PDF. may be i am missing something, any help will appreciate. 
For reference i added a fiddle.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var fb_type = "";
        var fb_src = "";

        $(".fancybox").click(function () {
            var varContent = "";
            var fb_type = $(this).attr("data-type");
            var fb_src = $(this).attr("data-src");
            console.log(fb_type);
            console.log(fb_src);
            if (fb_type == "image") {
                var varContent = '<img src="' + fb_src + '">';
            } else if (fb_type == "video") {
                var varContent = '<video width="100%" controls autoplay><source src="' + fb_src + '" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</video>';
            } else if (fb_type == "pdf") {
                var varContent = '<embed src="' + fb_src + '#nameddest=self&page=1&view=FitH,0&zoom=80,0,0" type="application/pdf" height="99%" width="100%" />';
            }

                $(".fancybox").fancybox({
                    //API options here
                    margin: [20, 60, 20, 60],
                    beforeLoad : function () {
                        console.log(varContent);
                    },
                    type: 'html',
                    content: varContent
                });         
            
        });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>



<a data-type="image" data-src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png" class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="javascript:;">Image</a>

<a data-type="video" data-src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="javascript:;">Video</a>

<a data-type="pdf" data-src="http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf" class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="javascript:;">PDF</a>
```

Comment: use the `data-fancybox-group` to have all the different type elements within the same gallery

Comment: remove the `type` property from your fancybox script and add the `data-fancybox-type` attribute to your tags. You won't actually need to bind a `click` event to your anchors to modify the type of content. Note: videos can use type as `html`, pdf as `iframe` and images as `image`

Comment: BTW, you can use html for videos if you are using a custom player like mediaelement js.... but you can use iframe (not cross-browser compatible) or use media helpers for specific source of videos (check the documentation)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5bthxw77/

Comment: @JFK Thanks for your reply, your suggestion is working fine and I have tested, but is there any way to avoid iframes ?